# Load BASE_URL page if username is not in session

Tags: php

I have `.php` script that need to redirect to another web page (BASE_URL) if username is not in session, but it's not working. Can someone help, please? Thank you.

In `verify.php` script is defined `BASE_URL,' http://www.mypage.com/login.html'.`

My script:

```
<?php 
require_once ('verify.php'); 
$page_title = 'My page';
ob_start();
session_start();
if (!isset($page_title)) {
$page_title = 'Login';}
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {    
$url = BASE_URL . ''; 
ob_end_clean(); 
header("Location: $url ");
exit(); 
}
?>
```

Comment: SO is not a debug tool. What did you tried to fix & debug that?

Comment: ***Firstly***, is `session_start();` inside ***ALL*** your files used?

Comment: @Fred Thanks, yes! But not working..

Comment: @strellson You're welcome. Try using `BASE_URL,'login.html'` instead or something to that affect. To be honest, I'm not very well-versed with `BASE_URL` but I would think that, if base url is already pointing to `http://www.mypage.com/` then it would make sense to leave that out and only define the page itself?

Comment: @strellson Try this `define('BASE_URL', 'http://www.mypage.com/login.html');` It worked for me.

Comment: @Fred Yes, that's exactly defined in `verify.php`..but not working, still not redirecting to another page without username in session.

Comment: @strellson It's hard to say for sure without knowing what is inside `verify.php`

Comment: @strellson Just to test, try removing `$url = BASE_URL . '';` see if that will work. Since `$url` is probably already defined in your `verify.php`?

Comment: @Fred In `verify.php` : `<?php 
session_start();
define('LIVE', TRUE);
define ('BASE_URL', 'http://mypage.com/login.html');
define ('MYSQL', 'db.php');`

Comment: @strellson Hm... maybe it's the `require_once` that's messing it up. Have you tried `require` only?

Comment: @strellson Or try taking out `define ('BASE_URL', 'http://mypage.com/login.html');` from your `verify.php` file and put it inside your code that you posted.

Comment: @Fred Already tried, but still nothing. :/

Comment: @strellson How/where is `($_SESSION['username'])` pre-defined? I suspect that if it's not referenced/defined anywhere, could be the problem. Sessions can be so problematic at times.

Comment: @strellson Try adding either `$_SESSION['$username'] = "username";` **or** `$username = $_SESSION['username'];` since it's not pre-defined. Maybe underneath `session_start();`

Comment: @Fred Here's the script for redirecting to members only area (sorry for the mess): `if($login_check > 0){
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 foreach( $row AS $key => $val ){
  $$key = stripslashes( $val );
 }
  
  session_register('username');
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
  session_register('password');
  $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
      
  header("Location: http://mypage.com/index.html?username=$username&password=$password");
 }`

Comment: @strellson Not a problem. Now that's inside `db.php` is it?

Comment: @Fred That's inside `verify.php`. Inside `db.php` is: `<?php


$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbusername = 'name';
$dbpasswd = 'pass';
$database_name = 'dbname';

$dbcon = mysql_pconnect("$dbhost","$dbusername","$dbpasswd") 
 or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");

$db = mysql_select_db("$database_name", $dbcon)
 or die("Couldn't select database.");
mysql_set_charset("utf8", $dbcon ); 

?>
`

Comment: @strellson I noticed that `session_start();` is not in `db.php` even though you stated that it's inside all other files, it should also be included in there as well. Try that and see what the results are.

Comment: @Fred still nothing..

Comment: @Fred Thank you for your time! I will try everything from the begining...must be some silly little mistake, because it's all seems alright..

Comment: @strellson You're welcome. I don't know how else I can help you. I suggest you re-post another question, but this time include all of your code in seperate bodies, and hopefully you will get a solution. Cheers, I wish you well :) (*Peace*)

Comment: @Fred After few hours I found that username is secretly stored in SESSION, even though it's not shown in web page link path. So I added new script `logout.php` with `session_destroy();`. Now everything is working fine. Thx again though. (Peace)

Comment: @strellson That's great news, I'm glad you managed to find what the problem was and found a solution, cheers! (*"Peace"*)

Comment: @strellson Might I suggest that you post it as answer, that way if other people fall on the same problem, they will have a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you do house cleaning work first.

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {    
    header("Location: $url ");
    exit;
}


require_once ('verify.php'); 
$page_title = 'My page';
ob_start();
if (!isset($page_title)) {
$page_title = 'Login';}
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that username is secretly stored in SESSION, even though it's not shown in web page link path. So I added new script `logout.php` with `session_destroy();`. Now everything is working fine.